# How to remove empty entries from a list in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'Fruits' : ['Mango', 'Banana', '', '', 'Apple'],
        'Trees' : ['Pine', 'Bamboo', '', '', '', '', ''],
        'Laptops' : ['Sony', '', '', 'LG', 'Acer', '']}
```

How can I remove all the EMPTY items from every list in dictionary, so it may look like this:

```
data = {'Fruits' : ['Mango', 'Banana', 'Apple'],
        'Trees' : ['Pine', 'Bamboo'],
        'Laptops' : ['Sony', 'LG', 'Acer']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a dict comprehension and `filter()`:

```
data = {k: filter(bool, v) for k, v in data.iteritems()}
```

or, for python 2.6 and older, where you do not yet have dict comprehensions:

```
data = dict((k, filter(bool, v)) for k, v in data.iteritems())
```

or a list comprehension for the value if you are on Python 3:

```
data = {k: [i for i in v if i] for k, v in data.iteritems()}
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> data = {'Fruits' : ['Mango', 'Banana', '', '', 'Apple'],
...         'Trees' : ['Pine', 'Bamboo', '', '', '', '', ''],
...         'Laptops' : ['Sony', '', '', 'LG', 'Acer', '']}
>>> {k: filter(bool, v) for k, v in data.iteritems()}
{'Laptops': ['Sony', 'LG', 'Acer'], 'Trees': ['Pine', 'Bamboo'], 'Fruits': ['Mango', 'Banana', 'Apple']}
```

Comment: You mean "a list comprehension if you are on Python 2", right?

Comment: Why `filter(bool, v)`? Isn't `filter(None, v)` exactly the same?

Comment: @BernhardKausler no, `filter` returns a list in Python 2, but an iterator in Python 3, hence the list comprehension.

Comment: @wRAR Python 2 has no dict comprehensions, only list comprehensions.

Comment: ah, they added dict comprehensions starting from Python 2.7

Comment: @BernhardKausler also, the second line uses a dict comprehension too.

Comment: @BernhardKausler: Python 2.7 added dict comprehensions; updated to include a py <= 2.6 version.

Comment: @Volatility: `filter(bool, v)` is exactly the same as `filter(None, v)` (the source of `filter` treats the two *exactly* the same), I've come to see `filter(bool, v)` as the more readable, self-documenting form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ifilter in itertools

```
from itertools import ifilter

for key,val in data.iteritems():
    data[key] = list(ifilter(lambda x: x!='', val))
```

Comment: Using `ifilter()` then calling `list()` on it completely defeats the purpose. You may as well use `filter()` directly then, which will be faster. `ifilter` takes `bool` as a filter too.